# Somar valores de dois array e transformar em uma unica variável Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante e continuo na saga de construir uma calculadora. **Não posso usar eval()**
Não sei se foi a escolha certa mas usei array para armazenar os números, já tentei usar uma terceira array para receber os resultado usando o push, mas o valor que me mostra sendo a variável result um array ou não, não é correto , então não sei exatamente onde errei.

```js
let tela = document.getElementById('visor');
let nums = [];
let oldnum = [];
let operation;
let result = 0;

function mostranum(num) {
  tela.innerHTML += num;
  nums.push(Number(num));
  console.log(nums)


}

function limpa() {
  nums.pop();
  tela.innerHTML = nums;

}

function operator(ope) {
  if (nums.length > 8) {
    nums.length = 8;
  }


  if (oldnum.length == 0) { // quer dizer que é a primeira operação
    oldnum = nums;
    console.log(`old num recebeu ${oldnum}`);
    //console.log(typeof nums)
    operation = ope;
    nums.splice(0);
    tela.innerHTML = '';


  } else if (oldnum.length != 0 && ope != 'result') {
    // executar a operação anterior
    oldnum = calcula(oldnum, nums, operation);
    console.log(`resultado ${oldnum}`);
    console.log(typeof oldnum);
  }
}


function calcula(num1, num2, oper) {
  for (let c = 0; c < num1.length; c++) {
    switch (oper) {
      case 'sum':
        result += num1[c] + num2[c];
        //result.push(parseInt(num1[c]) + parseInt(num2[c]));
        break;
      case 'subtract':
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
      case 'multiplication':
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
      case 'division':
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    }
  }
  return result;

}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d44b57;
}

#calculadora{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 350px;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: auto;

}

button{
    border: 0;
    background: #9d0229;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 16;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    
}

#visor{
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id='calculadora'>
  <button id='clear' onclick="limpa()">C</button>
  <div id="visor"></div>
  <button class="num" id="n7" value="7" onclick="mostranum(7)">7</button>
  <button class="num" id="n8" value="8" onclick="mostranum(8)">8</button>
  <button class="num" id="n9" value="9" onclick="mostranum(9)">9</button>
  <button class="ops" id="sum" onclick="operator('sum')">+</button>

  <button class="num" id="n4" value="4" onclick="mostranum(4)">4</button>
  <button class="num" id="n5" value="5" onclick="mostranum(5)">5</button>
  <button class="num" id="n6" value="6" onclick="mostranum(6)">6</button>
  <button class="ops" id="subtract" value="-" onclick="operator('subtract')">-</button>

  <button class="num" id="n1" value="1" onclick="mostranum(1)">1</button>
  <button class="num" id="n2" value="2" onclick="mostranum(2)">2</button>
  <button class="num" id="n3" value="3" onclick="mostranum(3)">3</button>
  <button class="ops" id="multiplication" value="*" onclick="operator('multiplication')">*</button>

  <button class="num" id="0" value="0" onclick="mostranum(0)">0</button>
  <button class="ops" id="float" value=".">.</button>
  <button class="result" id="result" onclick="operator('result')">=</button>
  <button class="ops" id="division" value="/" onclick="operator('division')">/</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta para poder correr código. Podes juntar o CSS para ficar mais visível?

Comment: seria mais simples usar 2 variáveis (primeiro e segundo número= e a operação... mesmo que queria fazer algo como 4+5+6+7+8...etc, tbm ia precisar de um array pra operação.. poderia ser 4+5/6*7 ... etc isso vai complicar demais seu código, mas isso mesmo que quer fazer?

Comment: Exatamente Ricardo Pontual, concordo 100%.

Comment: Então Ricardo, pensei assim: usando os botões o usuário insere o valor , depois o operador , depois o segundo número, mas caso ele não escolha finalizar a operação mas sim inserir um segundo operador , a operação que ele colocou primeiro ex: num 1 + num 2 , seria executada e o resultado armazenado na variável que recebe o primeiro numero e assim fazer o processo novamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma versão **bem** básica da calculadora poderia seguir esta lógica:

1. guardar um número
2. guardar a operação
3. guardar o outro número
4. se for digitado `=`, calcular a operação e atualizar o *display*
5. o resultado da operação passar a ser primeiro número
6. volta para o passo 2

No caso do passo 4, também poderia fazer o cálculo se for digitada uma operação. Estou considerando aquela calculadora básica, por exemplo:

- digito `2`: o visor mostra o número 2
- digito `+`: o visor não muda (mas internamente ele guardou a operação "soma")
- digito `3`: o visor mostra o número 3
- digito `-`: o visor mostra o resultado da operação anterior (2 + 3), ou seja, mostra `5`, e ao mesmo tempo já guarda a operação "subtração"
- digito `1`: o visor mostra o número 1
- digito `=`: o visor mostra 4 (resultado de 5 - 1)

E nos passos 1 e 3, também tenho que ir atualizando o número. Por exemplo, se eu digito `1` e depois `3`, o visor deve mostrar o número 13.

Também incluí uma limitação: se o número digitado passar de 9 dígitos, eu não atualizo. Enfim, uma versão inicial (ainda incompleta) ficaria assim:

```js
let tela = document.getElementById('visor');
let n1 = null, n2 = null, operacao = null;
let formatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 8, useGrouping: false });

function limpa() {
  tela.innerHTML = '';
  n1 = n2 = operacao = null;
}

function atualizaVisor(n) {
   tela.innerHTML = formatter.format(n);
}

function atualizaNumero(atual, novoDigito) { // adiciona um dígito no número atual
    if (atual === null) return novoDigito;

    let novo = atual * 10 + novoDigito;
    if (novo > 999999999) { // só aceito números de até 9 dígitos
        return atual; // retorna o atual, sem modificações
    }

    return novo;
}

function atualizaTela(digito) {
  if (operacao === null) {
    n1 = atualizaNumero(n1, digito);
    atualizaVisor(n1);
  } else {
    n2 = atualizaNumero(n2, digito);
    atualizaVisor(n2);
  }
}

function operator(op) {
  if (operacao !== null) {
     calcula();
  }
  operacao = op;
  if (n2 !== null) {
    calcula();
  }
}

function calcula() {
  let result;
  switch (operacao) {
    case '+':
      result = n1 + n2;
      break;
    case '-':
      result = n1 - n2;
      break;
    case '*':
      result = n1 * n2;
      break;
    case '/':
      result = n1 / n2;
      break;
  }
  atualizaVisor(result);
  n1 = result;
  n2 = operacao = null;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d44b57;
}

#calculadora {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 130px;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

button {
    border: 0;
    background: #9d0229;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 11;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#visor{
    width: 83px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id='calculadora'>
  <button id='clear' onclick="limpa()">C</button>
  <div id="visor"></div>
  <button class="num" id="n7" value="7" onclick="atualizaTela(7)">7</button>
  <button class="num" id="n8" value="8" onclick="atualizaTela(8)">8</button>
  <button class="num" id="n9" value="9" onclick="atualizaTela(9)">9</button>
  <button class="ops" id="sum" onclick="operator('+')">+</button>

  <button class="num" id="n4" value="4" onclick="atualizaTela(4)">4</button>
  <button class="num" id="n5" value="5" onclick="atualizaTela(5)">5</button>
  <button class="num" id="n6" value="6" onclick="atualizaTela(6)">6</button>
  <button class="ops" id="subtract" value="-" onclick="operator('-')">-</button>

  <button class="num" id="n1" value="1" onclick="atualizaTela(1)">1</button>
  <button class="num" id="n2" value="2" onclick="atualizaTela(2)">2</button>
  <button class="num" id="n3" value="3" onclick="atualizaTela(3)">3</button>
  <button class="ops" id="multiplication" value="*" onclick="operator('*')">*</button>

  <button class="num" id="0" value="0" onclick="atualizaTela(0)">0</button>
  <button class="ops" id="float" value=".">.</button>
  <button class="result" id="result" onclick="calcula()">=</button>
  <button class="ops" id="division" value="/" onclick="operator('/')">/</button>

</div>
```

Diminuí um pouco o tamanho dos botões para caber no *snippet* do site (mas como é somente estilização, depois você muda do jeito que achar melhor).

Incluí uma formatação para casas decimais (com no máximo 8 casas depois da vírgula) usando [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) (divida 1 por 3, por exemplo, o resultado ultrapassaria o limite do visor). Ainda sim não é totalmente correto, pois se o número for `1000000.123455676`, vai estourar o limite do visor (uma outra abordagem seria transformar o número em string e cortar pedaços do mesmo, ou transformar em notação científica).

Como eu já disse, **é uma versão incompleta**, apenas para dar uma ideia de onde você estava errando (veja que não precisava do array, bastava guardar o primeiro e segundo números e a operação atual).

Faltam outros detalhes, como:

- digitar números com casas decimais (se digitar `.`, não tem efeito nenhum por enquanto, mas bastaria ir adicionando as casas decimais nos números)
- limitar o tamanho do resultado (multiplique 1 milhão por 1 milhão, o resultado ultrapassará os limites do visor)

  - tratar melhor números negativos e com casas decimais: o sinal de `-` também ocupa uma posição do visor, assim como o ponto que separa as casas decimais (então não basta ver a quantidade de dígitos, teria que transformar em string mesmo e ver o tamanho)
- etc...

Mas a ideia básica está aí.

Answer (score 0):

Considerações:

1) Ao final de cada 'operação', você deve 'atualizar' o elemento visor

```
case 'sum':
        result += num1[c] + num2[c];
        tela.innerHTML = result;
        break;
```

Caso contrário, sua 'Memória' (result) sempre vai estar errada. Exemplo.: 8+8 fica igual a 88.

2) Sugiro usar um elemento input com atributo hidden pra armazenar o atual resultado da conta e não um array. Desta forma você sempre sabe o valor da última 'operação' porque ele vai estar lá no DOM.

```
<input id='resultado' type='hidden'>
ou
<div id='resultado' style='display: none'></div>
...

let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
...

resultado.innerHtml = resultado + num2; // porque num1 é o resultado.
```

Comment: Coloquei esse código que você me mandou mas não funcionou, na tela não estava aparecendo nada por que eu estou usando o console.log para testes, o resultado continua errado por algum motivo, obrigada pelas sugestões

Comment: Desculpe, mas não foi minha intenção corrigir teu código fonte. Na realidade te orientei a como resolver o seu problema, até porque sua dúvida tem muita semelhança com trabalhos acadêmicos solicitados por professores de algorítimo e te dar a resposta não é o melhor caminho. Se é uma questão acadêmica, então existe um melhor caminho: o método matemático chamado "Notação Polonesa Inversa"  que utiliza o conceito de "Pilha" (ou Array) para realizar as operações (e é isso que o professor quer). Se não é acadêmico, então podemos eliminar o uso de Array, como o amigo hkotsubo já desenrolou acima.